# Where does the 8 come from? Generic Search Problem with Bounded Probabilities

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, random-oracle-model, quantum-cryptography, probability, dilithium

I am working with lossy ID-schemes and their security in the QROM. Following the article of [Kiltz et al.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/916.pdf) , I am at a loss of the number 8 appearing in most reductions throughout the article. I know it comes from the *Generic Search Problem for Bounded Probabilites*, however how?

The Lemma from the article as wee as the game for a quantum adversary is:

[image]

With the following proof in the appendix:

[image]
[image]

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. I have been looking at line 02 for the $GSPB_{\lambda}$ game and wondering if it could have anything to do with the probability of $\lambda(x)$ being greater than $\lambda$ ?

I have also followed the proof to the [original source](https://www.iacr.org/archive/pkc2016/96140179/96140179.pdf), but nor here do I seem to find anything explaining the 8...

My main goal for looking at this was finding the bound for a classical adversary $\mathcal{B}$ against the GSPB. I would believe this to be simply $Pr[GSPB^{\mathcal{B}}_{\lambda} \Rightarrow 1] = \lambda \cdot Q$. Is this intuition right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the paper states, you should look directly at [HRS16, Theorem 1](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1256.pdf).
The proof there seems fairly straightforward, but it seems to depend on theorem 7.2 of [Zhandry2012](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/182.pdf).
This itself appears to depend on [another Zhandry2012](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/076.pdf), namely theorem 3.2

> **Theorem 3.2**. Fix $q$, and let $D_\lambda$ be a family of distributions on $H_{X,Y}$ indexed by $\lambda\in[0,1]$.
> Suppose there are integers $d$ and $\Delta$ such that for every $2q$ pairs $(x_i, r_i)\in X\times Y$, the function
> $p(\lambda) = \Pr_{H\gets D_\lambda}[H(x_i) = r_i\forall i\in\{1,\dots,2q\}]$ satisfies:
>
> - $p$ is a polynomial in $\lambda$ of degree at most $d$, and
> - $p^{(i)}(0)$, the $i$th derivative of $p$ at 0, is 0 for each $i\in\{1,\dots, \Delta-1\}$.
>
> Then any quantum algorithm $A$ making $q$ quantum queries can only distinguish $D_\lambda$ from $D_0$ with probability at most $\frac{4^\Delta}{(2\Delta)!}\lambda^\Delta d^{2\Delta}.$

It appears your paper later applies this with $\Delta = 1$ and $d = 2(Q+1)$, giving a bound of $\frac{4}{2}\lambda (2(Q+1))^2 = 8\lambda (Q+1)^2$.